# find_library("c") on Windows is broken?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to use czmq bindings:

https://github.com/zeromq/czmq/tree/master/bindings/python

When I load that module on Windows, it's trying to do the following:

`libcpath = find_library("c")`

Which reaches this function on Windows:

```
    def find_msvcrt():
        """Return the name of the VC runtime dll"""
        version = _get_build_version()
        if version is None:
            # better be safe than sorry
            return None
        if version <= 6:
            clibname = 'msvcrt'
        elif version <= 13:
            clibname = 'msvcr%d' % (version * 10)
        else:
            # CRT is no longer directly loadable. See issue23606 for the
            # discussion about alternative approaches.
            return None
```

Notice the line `# CRT is no longer directly loadable. See issue23606 for the`

Googling this issue:
https://bugs.python.org/issue23606

It seems like there solution was to add that else statement and return None. I couldn't find any alternative approaches.

Is there any way to get around this issue on Windows or to get czmq bindings working?

Comment: What call are you using to load the library?

Comment: @oda `libcpath = find_library("c")`

Comment: That shouldn't work on Windows, no? The ctypes documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#finding-shared-libraries),  states "[o]n Windows, `find_library()` searches along the system search path, and returns the full pathname, but since there is no predefined naming scheme a call like `find_library("c")` will fail and return `None`."

Comment: @oda it actually goes to find_msvcrt() as I explained in my comment but then that has an if statement (see last branch) that fails on modern Windows.